Flutter android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals() problem
I take that problem and opened white screen on the emulator

"I/e.temsa_attempt( 5896): Compiler allocated 4968KB to compile void
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()"

It was running 1 day ago but today it is not working, and i didn't change anything.
Image here
I just delete emulators and setup again but don't work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm also experiencing this same issue. Somehow clearing the cache of the app in the emulator enables it to run again without issues

I'm also experiencing this same issue. Somehow clearing the cache of the app in the emulator enables it to run again without issues
